# Question on the proof of Sylow's theorem for abelian groups in Herstein

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I think that by Cauchy's theorem, there is $Sx \in G/S$ such that $(Sx)^p=S$ and $Sx\neq S$.

But I don't know why the author emphasizes that "there is an $n$ with ${(Sx)^p}^n=S$" instead of $(Sx)^p=S$. Or is there anything that I missed?

Comment: You are right that Cauchy's theorem insures the existence of an element of order exactly $p$. But it seems that the author does not refer to Cauchy's theorem explicitely, they decide to use a weaker statement (namely the existence of an element of order a power of $p$) because it was enough for the sake of their proof. Is Cauchy's theorem proved somewhere earlier in the book ? If not, it may explain why the author decided not to use it.

Comment: @Suzet Cauchy's theorem for the abelian group case was just proved before this theorem.